# Inline CSS formatting best practices - Two questions

Tags: css

Question #1 - When specifying an inline style in an HTML element, is it necessary to include a trailing semi-colon? For example ...

```
<div style="padding:10px;">content</div>
```

Question #2 - When specifying an inline style should a space be inserted after the colon separating attribute name from attribute value?

```
<div style="padding: 10px;">content</div>
```

vs.

```
<div style="padding:10px;">content</div>
```

Comment: #1 yes you need to. #2 its only coding practice.

Comment: @anji, you only need semicolons to separate two styles. The last style does not need one.

Comment: Perhaps to clarify question/answer (Šime Vidas) for future visitors, it would be better to rephrase the second question: "should a space be insert" => "it's necessary to add a space" . It not the same to say "You should not" that to say "You don't need to".

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**Answer #1:** No.

Semi-colons are required only **between** declarations.

> A declaration-block (also called a
>   {}-block in the following text) starts
>   with a left curly brace ({) and ends
>   with the matching right curly brace
>   (}). In between there must be a list
>   of zero or more semicolon-separated
>   (;) declarations.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#rule-sets

> The value of the style attribute must
>   match the syntax of the contents of a
>   CSS declaration block (excluding the
>   delimiting braces)

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr/#syntax

Since you have only one declaration, there is nothing to separate, so no semicolons are needed.

However, the CSS syntax allows for **empty declarations**, which means that you can add leading and trailing semicolons as you like. For instance, this is valid CSS:

```
.foo { ;;;display:none;;;color:black;;; }
```

and is equivalent to this:

```
.foo { display:none;color:black }
```

---

**Answer #2:** No.

> A declaration is either empty or
>   consists of a property, followed by a
>   colon (:), followed by a value. Around
>   each of these there may be **whitespace**.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#declarations

You can add spaces in order to improve readability, but they have no relevance.

Comment: I'm blaming you when the next stylesheet I work with looks like `body { ;;;margin:0;;;padding:0;;; }` :)

Comment: @thirtydot Don't worry, writing such code would be senseless. It's a nice party trick though.

Comment: In fact you don't even need quotes on the style attribute if there's no spaces or certain other punctuation.  <div style=height:10px> works fine.  Doesn't pass xml, though, and nobody does it.

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**: Yes (if you have more than one inline-style specified. Even it's not required for the last one, it's a good practice to append `;` after each one).

[Quote](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/inline.php):

> The normal rules of CSS apply inside
> the style attribute. Each CSS
> statement must be separated with a
> semicolon ";" and colons appear
> between the CSS property and its
> value.

**Question 2**: No, but you can add it to be easier to read. For instance, Eclipse formatting automatically adds this space.

Answer (score 1):

Q1: No, but I always include a trailing semicolon. Some years ago that semicolon could be a reason to a wrong render (or lack of) by some browsers. I guess nowadays is not a problem.

Q2: No, both ways means the same. Your election to include an space after the colon should be based on personal preferences for legibility.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:** Not required for your first question as written, but you would need to have the semi-colon if multiple definitions were present.

**Question 2:** Spaces are not required unless you are separating values in a specific property, such as: `box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 #000;`

One reason that you may want to add them in anyway, at least in a CSS-file context, would be that if you ever needed to run the CSS through a post-processor, like Sass, not having the semi-colons at the end of the line will cause the compiler to fail.

**In summary, then:** For inline styles, the above answers apply, but for CSS in separate files on the file system, I would always add the extra semi-colons and spaces to make it easier to read. You can always run your CSS through a compressor when you are ready for production.