# how to remove the space in the top e in the bottom of a page?

Tags: html, css

I have this classic container:

```
.container { width: 910px;
             margin-left: auto;
             margin-right: auto;
             position: relative; 
             background-image:url(../images/background.png);
             background-repeat:repeat-y; }
```

but it creates a small space (like 5, 10 px) in the top and in the bottom of the page.

Why? And how can I fix it?

Comment: What html tag is .container addressing?

Comment: @gutierrezalex: A "classic container" is invariably a `div`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to zero the page's `margin` and `padding`, like this:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
```

Some people like to use a [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to handle problems like this.

Personally, I don't for reasons summed up here: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/no_css_reset/.

Comment: 2 question : is it better put 0px or 0? and why last definition is without ; ?

Comment: When it's `0px` (or `0em` or `0whatever`), you can leave out the `px` part (see: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#numbers0). I think it's better to leave out the `px` because it's marginally shorter and more readable. The last definition is without `;` because you can omit the last `;` if you like, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732486/inline-css-formatting-best-practices-two-questions/5732519#5732519

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
.container
{
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
```

You may also need to adjust the `margin` and `padding` of the "thing" that `.container` is within.

Comment: ? What do you mean with the last phrase? :)