# cursor: pointer on hover not working

Tags: html, css

I have two divs

```
<div id="hm-sp-lenovo-wr">
 .......

<div id="hm-sp-motorola-wr">
 .......
```

And in my css I have

```
#hm-sp-lenovo-wr:hover { cursor: pointer }
#hm-sp-motorola-wr:hover { cursor: pointer }
```

but when i hover over the divs no pointer appears ....i just want to make the user know that the div is clickable...

Here is the link to the [site](http://posnation.com/)....look at the middle right below the flash slider

any ideas

Comment: I just fixed it from the solution @Gazler provided...thanks again

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need it on the hover state (as the cursor is only visible when hovering on the element), you simply put cursor: pointer on the element.  Also, don't forget your closing semi-colons.

```
#hm-sp-lenovo-wr { cursor: pointer; }
#hm-sp-motorola-wr { cursor: pointer; }
```

Comment: [The semicolons are not required.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732486/inline-css-formatting-best-practices-two-questions)

Comment: @thirtydot: good point, thanks for providing the link.  I won't be rushing to remove it from the last property of all my css though.  ;)

Comment: well its not required but isnt it good practice because if you add another style on that element you may overlook that the previous semicolon is not there

Comment: @Tamer: The point I was making is that the semicolons are not relevant to *fixing the problem* you asked about. I'm not here to debate a subjective style choice. I could argue that omitting them is *better* because then you're used to both styles, so you won't ever make the mistake of not noticing if you come to edit someone else's CSS that does omit them. (true story)